# Consulta Dinâmica Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Senhores, estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho que montar uma consulta que funcione com varias views, por exemplo, uma de produtos ou uma de pessoas. Estou fazendo alguns testes com este código:

```
declare @coluna nvarchar(max)
declare @variavel nvarchar(max)
declare @view nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @view = 'viewTeste'
set @coluna = 'Nome'

set @variavel ='t'

set @sql = 'select * from' + @view + ' as PFW join tbl_teste1 on PFW.ID = tbl_teste1.ID where '+ @coluna + ' like ' + '%' + @variavel + '%'

exec (@sql)
```

Onde a usuário vai passar o nome da view a coluna que quer consultar e a variável

Porem este código está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Incorrect syntax near 't'.
```

Este 't' é a variável que o cidadão passou.

Como resolver?

Comment: Falta mais duas ''...  +   ''%'' + @variavel + ''%''

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza, obrigado, porem eu ja testei. Dá o seguinte erro `The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa corrigir sua query no like ,

Por exemplo;

```
select * from tabela where like '%dado%';
```

vaja que o dado esta entre '%%' no seu caso a query esta sendo montado sem os **''** .

```
select * from Fluxo_Contas where Nome like %t%
```

Quando teria que ser

```
select * from Fluxo_Contas where Nome like '%t%'
```

Corrija da seguinte forma.

```
declare @coluna nvarchar(max)
declare @variavel nvarchar(max)
declare @view nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @view = 'Fluxo_Contas'
set @coluna = 'Nome'

set @variavel = 'BANCO';

set @sql = 'select * from ' + @view + ' where '+ @coluna + ' like ' + '''%' + @variavel + '%'''

print @sql;

exec (@sql)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, alguns minutos antes de você responder já havia resolvido da seguinte forma: `set @sql = 'select * from uvwPessoaFisica as PFW join tblPessoaCliente on PFW.Código = tblPessoaCliente.IdPessoaCliente where '+ @coluna + ' like ''%' + @variavel + '%'''`. Porem sua resposta funcionou 1000%. Muito Obrigado. Mas me responde uma coisa, eu tentei fazer isto por meio de uma Stored Procedure, porem a query que a SP executa não reconhece o parâmetro passado como coluna, existe como passar um nome de coluna por meio de parâmetro na SP?

Comment: Você pode usar o `print @sql;` para ver o que esta sendo montado na query nesses casos.

Comment: Verdade, eu estava usando, porem não sabia que a forma correta que o print deveria exibir era assim `like '%t%'`

Comment: E como vc chama a  proc ? E de uma aplicação? Se for de preferência para montar a query dentro da aplicação.

Comment: Sim, é de uma aplicação que tem várias telas de busca "na realidade é uma tela que é chamada de vários lugares diferentes, mas que conforme a chamada, ela efetua uma pesquisa diferente", por isso minha ideia é criar uma SP que funcionasse com qualquer tela, era só passar o nome da view para a SP, qual coluna e a variável a ser pesquisada, o retorno estou pegando como datatable e passando para um datagrid.

Comment: @Robss70, não dar para entender porque sua proc não esta aceitando o parâmetro , se for o caso abra uma nova pergunta com essa duvida.

Comment: Existem várias perguntas sobre esta questão no stackoverflow em inglês, todas dizendo que não é possível passar nomes de colunas como parâmetro e aconselhando usar consulta dinâmica, porem sem explicação de por que exatamente não funciona. Vou abrir uma pergunta mais detalhada sobre esta questão. Muito obrigado.